# ServiceNow: Unable to get dirPagination library to work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, pagination, servicenow, dirpagination

Our team is building a widget in ServiceNow and trying to use the pagination library dir-pagination, but we can't seem to get it to work.  We're using the correct module name (angularUtils.directives.dirPagination) and we have the following in our html:

```
<tr ng-click="c.onWidget('batch_qa_form_list',item.sys_id, item.short_description);" 
            dir-paginate="item in c.onbCase | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchTable | itemsPerPage: 10 track by $index" 
            ng-if="item.case_visible">
</tr>

<dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
```

When we load the widget onto a page, we get the following warning in the console:

Pagination directive: the pagination controls cannot be used without the corresponding pagination directive, which was not found at link time.

What are we missing here to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You might have an issue with the `ng-if`, [as mentioned here](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/issues/169#issuecomment-107823635). You might try removing it to verify if it is a timing issue.